# Alternate class in a for loop?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm cycling through a list using `{% for item in list %}`  and I want to output something like this:

```
<li>One</li>
<li class='alternate'>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li class='alternate'>Four</li>
...
```

with the intention of styling the alternate lines a different colour.

Django (1.3) has no `mod` or `div` template tag operators. I know I can add them by manipulating the django source, but I'd rather not do that as I want to be able to package this app up.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Found myself the answer in the question linked!

Comment: Maybe, this better and simplier? http://jsfiddle.net/K3TuN/

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe That's awesome, but what's the compatibility like of that syntax?

Comment: IE<=8 don't like this selector. IE>=9 works fine. Other browsers seem to work fine too.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Site needs to be compatible back to IE8, so I'll stick with `divisibleby` for now, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about django's [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter...

```
{% for item in list %}

<li class= "{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}alternate{% endif %}"><Your value></li>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `cycle`:

```
<li {% cycle "class='alternate'" "" %}"
```